# Windows Server: audit space usage (latest files/folders added and size)

Tags: windows

i work in a design agency (designer, little knowledge on programming). we have a Windows Server machine (Windows Storage Server 2008) that holds all our jobs. it's going to go under maintenence soon, because it got really slow after a thunderstorm.

however, i'd like to know if there's a native way or something that can be done to find out the latest files/folders created and the space they use. because in the last month, there's been a huge increase in the space usage, coming to something like 20GB in one single day (it shouldn't be more than 4GB/day).

i'm looking for a way to find which jobs are with this unnecessary extra space and help people work the right way.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do this that i know of - however if you're ok with using the command prompt (in the server of course) then [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/380108) from @learnScrapy at SuperUser (with a few tweeks) should do the trick.

Something like:

```
forfiles /P D:\ /M *.* /S /D +"01/17/2012"  /C "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 209715200 echo @path @fsize @fdate @ftime"
```

You'd need to change D:\ to whatever path you store all your design work at, the date ("01/17/2012") would need to be changed to from whatever date you know the issue wasn't present yet (and maybe change the order depending on the server's regional settings (MM/DD/YYYY vs DD/MM/YYYY vs ....)), and finally change the value 209715200 to whatever minimum size you'd like to search files for - that value is 200MB.

If your projects span multiple files though, if all are smaller then the size you choose but there's just a awful lot of them making up for several GB then you can't know and this won't work. This will only find files with a date later than the one you specified with size larger then the one you specified in the path you specified.

Comment: thanks, 537mfb. but that goes beyond my knowledge on Windows and Networks.